# How to access nested collections Firestore React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access this data:
[image]

And this is what I'm trying, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
const nameRef = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('NegociosDev')
    .doc('Peluquerias')
    .collection('Negocios')
    .doc('PR01')
    .collection('citas')
    .doc('1xCDFWiDx3jUdKo8R3AG')
        nameRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({
                name: doc.data().Negocio
            })
            console.log(name)

        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `console.log` line refers to a variable `name` that is not defined in the database callback function, at least not that we can see.  First try logging like this to see everything in the document:

```
console.log(doc.data())
```

If doc.data() returns undefined, that means you fetched a document that doesn't exist, and you should double-check the names of the collections and documents you're using.

Comment: ".onSnapshot" is a listener, not a fetch - what are you expecting to cause a snapshot?  If you want to *fetch* the document, you have to use ".get()", and you have to remember it returns a *Promise* of a DocumentSnapshot, *not* the document.